# Does Twig 'date' support localised dates?

Tags: twig

Using this twig code in Craft CMS I'm getting the error shown below. The makers of Craft CMS tell me that the Twig 'date' does not support localized month names like "janvier 2016", but it's fine with English "January 2016".

Is this true?

**My Twig:**
{% set queryStartDate = date([month, year]|join(' ')) %}

**Error:**
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (janvier 2016) at position 0 (j): The timezone could not be found in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig's [date](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) function is just a wrapper for PHP's [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class.

Instead of passing in localized month names into the method, convert them to their numeric equivalents (January/Janvier = 01, etc.) and pass them into yyyy-mm-dd format.

Something like:

```
{% set queryStartDate = date(year ~ '-' ~ month ~ '01') %}
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, that led me to a solution.